# What does two capital DD letters mean in a file path

Tags: c#, .net, vba

Given the following code, is there a significance to what the `DD`does?

`dsData.WriteXml(appsetting_path & "\test\DD" & name & "_data.xml")`

This is from visual basic code and wondering if it can also apply to C# applications.

I recall reading something potentially about it but forgot what it was called.

Comment: It means a subfolder called "DD"?

Comment: Presumably the person writing it needed a static filename starting with the characters DD?

Answer (score 5):

Nothing. It has no special meaning, especially not as part of a file name.